# Is it possible to transfer or change an existing fan page to become an app's fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

The end goal is to have the "go to app" button on an existing non app fan page. I understand you can create an app fan page to do this but I do not want to lose/redirect the thousands of fans to a new fan page. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.